# Expand functionaility of SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I've got this function that returns the cost of staff working on a specific course, the course can have one or more lab assistens and one or more staff personal, this code works fine as long as there's only one staff and one assistent working on the specific course, I want to make it work for any ammount of staff and assistants, how can I expand this to get that functionality?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getCourseCost]
(
    @CourseCode varchar(50),
    @Year nchar(10),
    @Period nchar(10)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SSN_staff varchar(50)
DECLARE @Salary_staff int
DECLARE @Hours_staff int
DECLARE @Cost_staff int
DECLARE @Cost_labass int

SELECT @SSN_staff = SSN FROM Attended_By WHERE Period = @Period AND Year = @Year AND CourseCode = @CourseCode
SELECT @Salary_staff = Salary FROM Staff WHERE SSN = @SSN_staff
SELECT @Hours_staff = Hours FROM Attended_By WHERE Period = @Period AND Year = @Year AND CourseCode = @CourseCode
SELECT @Cost_labass = (Hours * Salary) FROM Labass WHERE Period = @Period AND Year = @Year AND CourseCode = @CourseCode

SET @Cost_staff = @Salary_staff * @Hours_staff
IF @Cost_staff is NULL
BEGIN
SET @Cost_staff = 0
END

IF @Cost_labass is NULL
BEGIN
SET @Cost_labass = 0
END

RETURN @Cost_staff + @Cost_labass
END
```

Comment: Although I could probably guesstimate from your code above, in order for the question to be answered more easily it may be useful for you to define what the tables `Attended_By`, `Staff`, and `Labass` are for and what the columns for these mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to make some assumptions about your tables from your code, as I'm not explicitly sure what they are, but assuming that `Attended_By.Hours` is the number of hours attended by a member of staff on the course, and `Staff.Salary` dictates the cost of the staff member per hour, the following query should give you a single cost for all staff on the course:

```
SELECT  @Cost_Staff = SUM(A.Hours * S.Salary)
  FROM  Attended_By A
    INNER JOIN Staff S ON S.SSN = A.SSN
  WHERE (Period = @Period AND
        Year = @Year AND
        CourseCode = @CourseCode)
```

This will SUM all of the the hours for each staff member multiplied by their respective salary.
Using the above, you can dispense with all three `SELECT`s for `@SSN_staff`, `@Salary_staff`, and `@Hours_staff`.

I believe that the query you are using for lab assistants should already return the total if you use the `SUM` function:

```
SELECT  @Cost_labass = SUM(Hours * Salary)
  FROM  Labass
  WHERE (Period = @Period AND
        Year = @Year AND
        CourseCode = @CourseCode)
```

Comment: Yep, that is correct, thanks alot for the quick answer.